# dll found but cannot be loaded from current working directory

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, ctypes

I have the following code I am running:

```
def PATH():
    return "\n"+"\n".join(os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep))

def syspath():
    return "\n"+"\n".join(sys.path)

def test_haha():
    logger.info(f"CWD: {os.getcwd()}")
    logger.info(f"sys.path: {syspath()}")
    logger.info(f"PATH: {PATH()}")

    logger.info(f"Found? {str(util.find_library('PCANBasic'))}")
    windll.LoadLibrary("PCANBasic")
    # pcanbasic_path = str(Path(os.getcwd()) / "PCANBasic.dll")
```

And my `PCANBasic.dll` is sitting in my working directory. I am using windows 10.

If I run python from the command line, everything works correctly.

However, I have a IDE written in pyqt and bundled with PyInstaller. That IDE has a function to run a python file (calling a QProcess in a batch file that runs the same command I am running manually), and in this case it fails with the following:

```
    def test_haha():
        logger.info(f"CWD: {os.getcwd()}")
        logger.info(f"sys.path: {syspath()}")
        logger.info(f"PATH: {PATH()}")

        logger.info(f"Found? {str(util.find_library('PCANBasic'))}")
>       windll.LoadLibrary("PCANBasic")

demo_test\test_dll.py:23: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
C:\Users\myuser\python3_portable\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:434: in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <WinDLL 'PCANBasic', handle 0 at 0x1e9e6480668>, name = 'PCANBasic'
mode = 0, handle = None, use_errno = False, use_last_error = False

    def __init__(self, name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None,
                 use_errno=False,
                 use_last_error=False):
self._name = name
        flags = self._func_flags_
        if use_errno:
            flags |= _FUNCFLAG_USE_ERRNO
        if use_last_error:
            flags |= _FUNCFLAG_USE_LASTERROR
        if _sys.platform.startswith("aix"):
            """When the name contains ".a(" and ends with ")",
               e.g., "libFOO.a(libFOO.so)" - this is taken to be an
               archive(member) syntax for dlopen(), and the mode is adjusted.
               Otherwise, name is presented to dlopen() as a file argument.
            """
            if name and name.endswith(")") and ".a(" in name:
                mode |= ( _os.RTLD_MEMBER | _os.RTLD_NOW )

        class _FuncPtr(_CFuncPtr):
            _flags_ = flags
            _restype_ = self._func_restype_
        self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr

        if handle is None:
>           self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
E           OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

The cwd, `sys.path` are identical and `PATH` are mostly the same (the IDE version has the PyQt5 bin folder).

In summary, the questions are:

1 - What could be causing this difference of behaviour, when in one case I am able to load a dll from the current working directory, and in the other case I am not?

2 - In any case if the dll is in any directory in PATH it works. Maybe is it a bad practice to rely on dlls in the working directory, and install them somewhere properly instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow a tutorial using Process Monitor and filtering with:

- operation is `CreateFile`
- path contains `PCANBasic`

I was able to see that the PyInstaller bundle was having a different search path then the direct command.

I then found [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3795) that mentions that PyInstaller uses the `SetDllDirectoryA` call to add the bundle's own folder to the DLL search path but with the side-effect of removing the current directory.